# Duplicate File Error in library Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm using both library for my projects.

```
implementation 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.5.2' 

implementation 'com.connectsdk:connect-sdk-android:1.6.0'
```

When i'm build my proejct then it's give duplicate class error.

Please anyone give answer of this issue.

Thank You.

Comment: please add the error message to your question

Answer (score 0):

You have to exclude that class from the library you don't use in like this:

```
implementation ('com.connectsdk:connect-sdk-android:1.6.0'){
   exclude group: 'class name', module: 'class name'
}
```